# Need explanation for list comprehension in Haskell

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I'm just starting with functional programming and I am learning Haskell programming language. Due to the fact that I am just a beginner, I have a piece of code and I need an explanation about this:

```hs
ghci> let xxs = [[1,3,5,2,3,1,2,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,4,2,1,6,3,1,3,2,3,6]]
ghci> [ [ x | x <- xs, even x ] | xs <- xxs]
-- Output: 
-- [[2,2,4],[2,4,6,8],[2,4,2,6,2,6]]
```

I see this code will produce the new list with the even numbers in each sub-list.

But I don't know why `x <- xs` and then `xs <- xxs`, why can't we do `x <- xxs` in the first place?

Comment: The `x` will be a sublist.

Comment: BTW, the recommended way of writing this is `filter even <$> xxs`, no list comprehension needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xss` is a list of *list*s of numbers. Let us assume it has type `[[Int]]` (the number type can be different, but that does not make any difference).

This means that if we define a generator `xs <- xxs`, then `xs` will have the type of the elements of that list, so `[Int]`. An `[Int]` is *not* an `Integral` type, so we can not check if a list of `Int`s is [**`even :: Integral a => a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:even).

We can however process that sublist `xs` further. For example with another list comprehension, like `[ x | x <- xs, even x ]` that filter the sublist.

It might however be more clear what you do with:

```
[ filter even xs | xs <- xss ]
```

or we can here convert the outer list comprehension to a simple `map`:

```
map (filter even) xss
```